# iPhone:how to get a value from NSMutable Array with keys

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsdictionary

I would like to know how to fetch a value from a NSMutableArray with keys. The array is built like this:

```
    qtype = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    while (dicjson = (NSDictionary*)[enumerator nextObject]) {
     question_id = [dicjson objectForKey:@"question_id"];        
     question_text = [dicjson objectForKey:@"question_text"];
     question_type = [dicjson objectForKey:@"question_type"];

     [qtype addObject:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:question_type forKey:question_id]];

}
```

I am populating the array in a table cell:

```
 -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
NSString *type = [qtype objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

}
```

however the output is like "65 = YN" which is not what i want. I would like to extract only "65".
If you could give me some idea, would be very much appreciated.

Comment: I believe this is not possible on a NSMutableArray. NSMutableDictionary will do this.

Answer (score 1):

It seems the dictionary for the question type contains only one key, so you can achieve what you want, but remember : dictionaries are **unordered** collections working with keys, whereas arrays are **ordered** collections working with indexes.

Anyway, in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, modify the code to get the only key (which is the question id) in the dictionary :

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
        cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSArray *dictKeys = [[qtype objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]] allKeys];
    NSString *type = [dictKeys objectAtIndex:0];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the fact, I really don't understand why you use an array of dictionaries.
You can simply build array of question texts:

```
qtype = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
while (dicjson = (NSDictionary*)[enumerator nextObject]) {
 question_id = [dicjson objectForKey:@"question_id"];        
 question_text = [dicjson objectForKey:@"question_text"];
 question_type = [dicjson objectForKey:@"question_type"];

 [qtype addObject:question_id];

 } 

 -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
NSString *type = [qtype objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

}
```

But if you need qtype for other purposes, you can get

```
 -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSDictionary *dict = [qtype objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
    NSString *type = [[dict allKeys] objectAtIndex:0]; 

}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works for me. I need to do it like that because it's reading json code from a server.

Answer (score 0):

It is because you store NSDictionary in "qtype". Try:

```
NSDictionary *dict = [qtype objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
NSString *type = [[dict allValues] lastObject];//since you have only one object stored.
```

Answer (score 0):

you can access each object of array which is of `NSDictionary` type.Following is the code for that

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSDictionary *dict = [qtype objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
    NSString *question_id = [dict objectForKey:@"question_id"];     
    NSString *question_text = [dict objectForKey:@"question_text"];
    NSString *question_type = [dict objectForKey:@"question_type"];
}
```